# Minima of a function

Tags: calculus, optimization

Let $F:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$ Is $\inf_{x,y} F(x,y)$ always equal to $\inf_{x} \inf_{y} F(x,y)$?

Comment: It is obvious that $inf_{x,y} F(x,y) \leq \inf_{x} \inf{y} F(x,y).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

$F(x,y) \geq \inf_y F(x,y) \geq \inf_x \inf_y F(x,y)$, for all $x,y$. Hence $\inf_{x,y} F(x,y) \geq \inf_x \inf_y F(x,y)$.

Similarly, $F(x,y) \geq \inf_{x,y} F(x,y)$, hence $\inf_y F(x,y) \geq \inf_{x,y} F(x,y)$, and hence $\inf_x \inf_y F(x,y) \geq \inf_{x,y} F(x,y)$.

So they are equal...